# How can I forward blocked http/https traffic by IP Tables to another host?

Tags: iptables

I have a huge list of IP Addresses blocked by iptables with rules set to DROP all of their traffic. The main traffic that comes is either http (port 80) or https (port 443). Is there a way (without manually editing every single rule) to forward requests from blocked sources to another server to show an error page explaining that traffic from the IP Address is blocked? The IP Ranges blocked belong to data centers and/or VPN Providers.

**Example IP Tables Rule**

```
-A INPUT -s 1.2.3.4/0 -j DROP
```

That's the format I have for each rule. I am using iptables-persistent to save these rules. Is there a simple rule I can add at the bottom that if the request is to port 80 or 443 the traffic would forward to another server? All other traffic (traffic through SSH, etc, needs to stay blocked). Is this doable?

Comment: You could use FAIL2BAN to look for blocked addresses and redirect port 80 and 443 traffic to a different server.  There would be quite a bit of customising to do it though.

Comment: davidgo - Would that look for the addresses blocked by IP Tables? I am willing to learn and would like to resolve this issue as fast as possible.

Comment: Actually, I missed that the ban source was a list, rather then an action taken by the web server - so FAIL2BAN is not your tool.   Why not modify the way the rules are written (for example using SED) prior to input, and make them in the form "IPTABLES -I PREROUTING -s XXX.XX.XX.XX -j DNAT --to-destination YY.YY.YY" and ensure there is an accept rule as well.